# Как сделать загрузку файла на workupload.com через Python?

Tags: python, веб-скрейпинг

мне нужно загрузить файл на workupload(или на другой файлообменник без регистрации доступный на територии рф), а затем получить на него ссылку. Искал в интернете, на моё удивление тема совершенно не популярная. В интернете не нашёл никаких библиотек для работы с данным сервисом.